# Problem Displaying Dynamic Data in Modal in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components, ng-bootstrap, angular4-forms

I'm trying to display reusable modal from my shared module to another module. My problem is I'm trying to make the data dynamic. I can already see the modal but the  dynamic data is not being shown. I'm trying to display it in the user.html. What is the problem to this? See this code below.

> Reusable Modal HTML

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">
    <b>Edit User</b>
  </h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="px-0">
      <div class="form-body">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="modalFormTmpl"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="modalButtonTmpl"></ng-container>
</div>
```

> Reusable.ts

```
export class ReusableModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChild('modalForm') modalFormTmpl: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('modalButton') modalButtonTmpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

> Shared Module

```
@NgModule({
      exports: [
        ReusableModalComponent,
        CommonModule,
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        ReusableModalComponent
      ],
      entryComponents: [
        ReusableModalComponent
      ]
    })
    export class SharedModule { }
```

> User.html

```
<app-reusable-modal>
  <ng-container #modalForm>
    <h1>jfpweoj</h1>
  </ng-container>
</app-reusable-modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Input decorator

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core';


export class ReusableModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChild('modalForm') modalFormTmpl: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('modalButton') modalButtonTmpl: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input() modalData: any; 

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and then anytime that component is declared you can just bind data into it through the `modalData` property through it like this

```
<app-reusable-modal [modalData] = "yourData">
  <ng-container #modalForm>
    <h1>jfpweoj</h1>
  </ng-container>
</app-reusable-modal>
```

hope this helps